# how to get path for import of javascript from file

Tags: javascript, k6

I have a file where i defined the absolute path of directory.

```
Ex : script=/absolutepath/scripts
utility=/absolutepath/utility
```

I want to use "script"/"utility" instead of absolute path in other javascript files.How i can do this.

What i want :

```
import random from "script/random.js"
```

instead of

```
import random from "/absolutepath/scripts/random.js"
```

PS :I am using k6 load generating framework which doesn't support node modules.

Answer (score 1):

You currently can't do that in k6 v0.26.0.

Import paths like that are reserved for internal k6 modules (e.g. `k6/http`) and "magic" remote import URLs (e.g. `import from github.com/loadimpact/k6/samples/thresholds_readme_example.js` instead of `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loadimpact/k6/master/samples/thresholds_readme_example.js`, and we're trying to softly discourage this). You can't define your own, you either have to use relative paths or absolute paths when importing your own JS files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using **importmaps**.

Inside your `index.html`:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script type="importmaps">
        {
            "imports": {
                "random": "/absolutePath/scripts/random.js"
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

</html>
```

You can now import your module from ANYWHERE

```
import random from 'random'
```